# File Picker for Android

Tags: android, file-io, filepicker

Is there any picker available to pick file from the SDCard or Device memory,like FilePicker available in Blackberry?
If not ,then any alternative for doing this?

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is the help for implementing [File picker](https://github.com/Kaloer/Android-File-Picker-Activity).

You can also see the [out put here](http://www.kaloer.com/android-file-picker-activity.)

Answer (score 3):

Although there are several out there on web, but the one that I personally use is [IO file manager](http://openintents.org/en/filemanager) its easy to use and integrate

**Update:** Link to [latest repo](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/source/browse/#svn/trunk/samples/TestFileManager)

Comment: Thanks,but i want source code,this gives me ".apk".

Answer (score 0):

There is no standard file picker for Android - which is sad... Nevertheless there are lots of implementations of file browser/picker Intents, applications and sources. You can Google them around and find what meets to your requirements.

I have written file picker for myself and it tooks several hours and Google browsing and some coding.